# Namespace definition in root element which is also namespaced - valid XML?

Tags: xml, xmpp, dart, xml-namespaces

My client is having a friendly XMPP conversation with the [Facebook chat server](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) and receives XML fragments which look like this:

```
<stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' from='chat.facebook.com' id='1' version='1.0' >
</stream:stream>
```

So there's a namespace definition "stream" on the root element. So far so good.

But the root element *itself* is using the "stream" namespace, which seems odd. Is this valid XML?

The XML library I'm using ([dart-xml](https://github.com/prujohn/dart-xml)) complains about it, I wonder if rightfully so or if that library has a [bug](https://github.com/prujohn/dart-xml/issues/36).

Comment: The scope of a namespace is the element in which it is declared and contained elements.  Therefore it's perfectly valid for the ns to be used in the element in which it's declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the root element itself is using the "stream" namespace, which
>   seems odd. Is this valid XML?

It's not odd that the root element itself is using the `stream` namespace, however...

Valid would have to be relative to an XSD, and the XSD would have to be associated with the XML instance.  I see that there is an XSD at the endpoint specified by the namespace: `http://etherx.jabber.org/streams.xsd`.

A common way to make the association would be to use an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute:

```
<stream:stream xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams http://etherx.jabber.org/streams.xsd"
               from='chat.facebook.com' id='1' version='1.0'>
</stream:stream>
```

Validation can then find the XML Schema to use, however, there's a problem:

```
[Error] streams.xsd:23:21: cos-nonambig: WC["urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"] and WC[##other:"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"] (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.
[Error] streams.xsd:74:21: cos-nonambig: "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams":text and WC[##other:"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"] (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.
```

The [Unique Particle Attribution](http://www.w3.org/wiki/UniqueParticleAttribution) is a required constraint of an XSD.  Therefore, to answer your question, we cannot say that the XML is valid because we do not have a valid XSD against which to base the validation.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like there's indeed a bug in the XML library which is about to get fixed: https://github.com/prujohn/dart-xml/issues/36#issuecomment-26763161